# How to disable postback on an asp Button (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)

Tags: .net, asp.net, javascript, ajax

I have an asp button.  It's server-side so I can only show it for logged in users, but i want it to run a javascript function and it seems when it's runat="server" it always calls the postback event.

I also have a regular button (`<input...`>) not running at server and it works fine...

How can I make this button only run the javascript and not postback?

Answer (score 280, accepted):

Have your javascript return false when it's done.

```
<asp:button runat="server".... OnClientClick="myfunction(); return false;" />
```

Comment: In many cases people use an onclick or OnClientClick with this syntax <asp:Button OnClientClick="myFunction()" /> where myFunction() returns false and this isn't enough - you have to use OnClientClick="return myFunction()"

Comment: I had to add UseSubmitBehavior="False" as well as ;return false

Comment: Make sure to add 'CausesValidation="false"', otherwise it will add 'WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions' and a bunch of extra markup.

Comment: This didn't work for me in ASP.NET 4+, however Konstantin's answer of simply `OnClientClick="return false"` did work.

Answer (score 41):

```
YourButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return false");
```

or

```
<asp:button runat="server" ... OnClientClick="return false" />
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use jquery click action and use the **preventDefault()** function to avoid postback

```
<asp:button ID="btnMyButton" runat="server" Text="MyButton" />


$("#btnMyButton").click(function (e) {
// some actions here
 e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: This is an elegant answer because it allows you to test for conditions to disable.

Comment: Never use preventDefault as it will stop other events that rely on this event -1

Comment: @ppumkin: preventDefault is a great way to tell other event listeners that you handled this event so they don't have to do so.
I think what you meant was stopPropagation, which indeed stops the event from even being heard by other event listeners.

Comment: Yeaaaaaaaaaa. no. 4 Years later and I stand behind this even more now. Just don't do any of that.

Comment: @PiotrKula How about another 4 years later? You can't just say dont do that. Obviously it's fine for the vast majority of cases. And convenience is worth a lot.

Comment: It is still not fine till today.. its the biggest misbelieve I see in JavaScript. preventDefault is eval() .. err evil..

Answer (score 8):

Consider this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequest);
function BeginRequest(sender, e) {
    e.get_postBackElement().disabled = true;

}
     </script>
```

Comment: A bit more context to your answer would be nice

Answer (score 6):

The others are right that you need your callback to return false; however I'd like to add that doing it by setting the onclick is an ugly old way of doing things.  I'd recommend reading about [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).  Using a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) could make your life easier, and the HTML less coupled to your javascript (and jQuery's [supported by Microsoft](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/28/jquery-and-microsoft.aspx) now!)

Answer (score 5):

ASP.NET always generate `asp:Button` as an `input type=submit`.
If you want a button which doesn't do a post, but need some control for the element on the server side, create a simple HTML input with attributes `type=button` and `runat=server`.

If you disable click actions doing `OnClientClick=return false`, it won't do anything on click, unless you create a function like:

```
function btnClick() {
    // do stuff
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't say which version of the .NET framework you are using.

If you are using v2.0 or greater you could use the OnClientClick property to execute a Javascript function when the button's onclick event is raised.

All you have to do to prevent a server postback occuring is return `false` from the called JavaScript function.

Answer (score 3):

additionally for accepted answer you can use UseSubmitBehavior="false" 
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior.aspx)

Comment: ASP.NET adds ;`__doPostBack(` to the end of client click script.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I solved adding return in the onClientClick:

### Code Behind

```
function verifyField(){
  if (document.getElementById("inputId").checked == "") {
    alert("Fill the field");
    return false;
  }
}
```

### Design Surface

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="send" Text="Send" onClientClick="return verifyField()" />
```

Comment: How to run `OnClick` method after this.

Answer (score 2):

With Validation

In this example I used two controls,`ddl` and `txtbox`, have a happy coding

```
 asp:ScriptManager ID="script1" runat="server" /asp:ScriptManager

    asp:UpdatePanel ID="Panel1" runat="server"
       ContentTemplate

// ASP BUTTON
asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" class="btn btn-success" OnClientClick="return Valid()" OnClick="btnSave_Click"


   /ContentTemplate    
    /asp:UpdatePanel    

  <script type="text/javascript">
        function Valid() {

            if ($("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_YOUR CONTROL NAME").val() == 0) {
                alert("Please select YOUR TEXT");
                $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_YOUR CONTROL NAME").focus();
                return false;
            }

            if ($("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_YOUR CONTROL NAME").val().length == 0) {
                alert("Please Type YOUR TEXT");
                $("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_YOUR CONTROL NAME").focus();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the code:

```js
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server"
     Text="Pulsa"
     OnClientClick="this.disabled=true"
     UseSubmitBehavior="False"/>
```

if nee submit

```js
...
<form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="deshabilita()">
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    function deshabilita()
    {
        var btn = "<%= Button1.ClientID %>";
        if (confirm("Confirme postback"))
        {
            document.getElementById(btn).disabled = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use JQuery for this

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnID" />
```

than in JQuery

```
$("#btnID").click(function(e){e.preventDefault();})
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to return false from the

```js
function jsFunction() {
  try {
    // Logic goes here
    return false; // true for postback and false for not postback
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e.message);
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<asp:button runat="server" id="btnSubmit" OnClientClick="return jsFunction()" />
```

JavaScript function like below.

**Note***: Always use try-catch blocks and return false from catch block to prevent incorrect calculation in javaScript function.