# How do you modify a modal popup from ASP codebehind instead of letting it close?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, code-behind, simplemodal

I'm using SimpleModal to create a popup on an ASP.net application.  The OK button calls a server-side function - and based on the resulta of that function I'd like to modify the popup (make some things visible, etc.) instead of letting it close.  If that's too difficult, I'd like to open the popup again without the user having to re-click on anything.  I'm just not sure what the best way to do this is.

Currently the OK button in the popup looks like this:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="submitInfoBtn" OnClick="btnSubmitInfo_Click"
           ImageUrl="css/assets/btn_ok.png" runat="server"/>
```

and there is nothing defined that tells anything that the OK button should close the popup (the Cancel button has class="simplemodal-close", so I would expect it to do just that, but not the OK button) - anyone have any ideas on the best way through this?  Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Javascript handler for the button with *return false*.  See...
[How to disable postback on an asp Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683746/how-to-disable-postback-on-an-asp-button)

Notice the return false.  This will prevent a Postback.

Now you can get any server data that you need using Ajax in your Javascript button handler and use JQuery to modify your Popup.

By the way, you can also use [JQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) for modal popups.  You may have much more support using that.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I jsut tried that - however, if I put in the "return false", my server-side code doesn't run (OnClick="btnSubmitInfo_Click" now seems to be dead in the water.) Is there a way to run the server function AND still keep the popup on the screen?

Comment: That was my point.  You return false and call the postback via an AJax call.  The popup stays and you get the result data via AJax.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so difficult, see my code of the pop up window. There is an OK button in the pop up, sometimes clicking OK will modify the pop up window, sometimes clicking will close the window, do I have a misunderstanding?

```
void OK_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      if (DataIsValid())
      {
        Save();
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "closeWindow", "<script type='text/javascript'>self.opener=null; self.close();</script>");
      }
      else ErrorLabel.Visible = true;
   }
   catch { ErrorLabel.Visible = true; }

}
```

Comment: It appears that your script will colse the entire window... I need to 'close' a popup that opens via SimpleModal - which actually displays a <div> section of the page as if it were a popup using jquery.  I want to keep the page itself open regardless.  Thanks, though, but not quite what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the SimpleModal `onShow` callback to bind to the OK button, make the ajax request, then check the response and show the new content.

You shouldn't use the `onClose` callback because it's just for animating the close or any cleanup. You can programatically close the dialog when you are ready with `$.modal.close();`

It will involve checking the dimensions of the returned content and adjusting the modal dimensions accordingly.

Have a look at the flickr badge viewer demo (http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/) for an example of what I'm talking about.