# Using an asp.net button to launch html code

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net, visual-studio

I want to use an asp.net button to launch an outlook window using the following html.

```
<a href="mailto:sample@website.com?subject=Insurance Text">
```

What do I need to do to file html code from my onClick event?

Comment: Can I ask why a button and not just the anchor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<asp:Button runat="server" 
            ID="btn" 
            OnClientClick="document.location = 'mailto:sample@website.com?subject=Insurance Text'; return false;"
            Text="Mail" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches. If you want the standard button, you could use something like this:

```asp
<asp:Button ID="MailToButton"
            Text="Send Email"
            OnClientClick="javascript: navigate('mailto:blah@blah.com'); return false;"
            runat="server" />
```

*EDIT 2: Never mind about the `UseSubmitBehavior` property - I was incorrect. You'll just have to use `return false;`. Apparently ASP.NET does not render a regular non-submit button. [How to disable postback on an asp Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683746/how-to-disable-postback-on-an-asp-button)*

If you want an anchor tag, you can just use the NavigateUrl property of the Hyperlink tag:

```asp
<asp:HyperLink ID="MailToHyperlink"
               Text="Send Email"
               NavigateUrl="mailto:blah@blah.com"
               runat="server" />
```

You cannot launch Outlook from the standard click event in the code behind, however. The code behind click event occurs on the server, not on the client's machine, so whatever you do it needs to happen on the client's machine either through standard HTML or through javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Why an ASP.NET button?
Just use a simple HTML button.

They are plenty of example on the web. This one should work: [using mailto button click event](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/463376-using-mailto-button-click-event)