# calling a web method from clientside using jquery ajax method - not calling method rather going into pageload

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery, client-side-scripting

I click my edit button,it enters button click function in javascript.When ajax() is executed  the control goes to page load of WebForm rather than directly calling update() of webform which I'm mentioning as [ url: "WebForm1.aspx/update",] in ajax().Why not my update function is invoked ?? 
    I'm having master page for my webform and the button is an asp:control

```
This is my javascript
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("input[id*='edit']").click(function () {
        var userdata = {};
        userdata["Name"]="Saran";
        var DTO = { 'userdata' : userdata};
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "WebForm1.aspx/update",
            data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                //do something
                alert("SUCCESS = " + result);
                console.log(result);
            },

            error: function (xmlhttprequest, textstatus, errorthrown) {
                alert(" conection to the server failed ");
                console.log("error: " + errorthrown);
            }
        });//end of $.ajax()

        return false;
    });//eof button click
});


and my webform looks like this

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;
using Payoda.Assignments.BusinessLayer;

namespace Payoda.Assignments.LoginApplication
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static string update(string userdata)
        {
            return "success";
        }
    }
}


my aspx page looks like this

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MyMasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TrialPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="Application.TrialPage" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/TrialScript.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Contents" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="editLink" runat="server" Text="MY BUTTON" />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683746/how-to-disable-postback-on-an-asp-button) on how to avoid postback for your asp:control buttons.

Comment: @LeonStafford i wanted to invoke a particular method in the server side rather than going through full cycle of asp.

Comment: I found the error i mentioned as "contenttype" rather than "contentType".Thank you for the suggestions

Comment: glad you found it. so this should have been picked up in the JavaScript console I believe? It is always good to check for any console errors and do usual debugging of frontend/backend before posting on SO, but glad to see you have joined and hope to see more questions and answers from you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake...
one of the $.ajax parameters which is contentType is written wrongly as contenttype whereas the correct format is "contentType"...

Answer (score 0):

You should use a regular html input instead of asp:button