# how to get only one button to fire the form action

Tags: asp.net, html, forms

I have a asp 4.0 application with multiple buttons on it but I want only one to fire the form event.

At this moment it doesn't matter which button I press on the form they all fire the form event.

How do I accomplish it that the event only fires at 1 certain button?

Answer (score 0):

[How to disable postback on an asp Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683746/how-to-disable-postback-on-an-asp-button)

You can add

```
    UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="myfunction(); return false;"
```

to asp buttons that you do not want to post back. Alternatively you could use standard HTML buttons, rather than asp:Button is you don't want them to submit the form.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

Comment: I tried that but that way all my codebehind doesn't work.
Would it be possible to call the action from code behind somehow?