# Page is posting back after use of PageMethod

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I want to do search functionality in my popup.

It contains textbox and button and a grid to show result.

Popup is viewd as follows:

[image]

After clicking search button i have called a javascript function to have call on serverside function to bind the grid.

But after clicking of search button popup vanishes.

Search button is as follows:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" 
                     OnClientClick="javascript:showGrid();return false;"></asp:Button>
```

Javascript function:

```
function showGrid() {

        PageMethods.Search("onResult");

        return false;

    }
    function onResult() {

        return false;
    }
```

Search function on server side(.cs)

```
[WebMethod]
    public void Search()
    {
        availableMembers();
    }
```

But when i checked call only goes to javascript function `showGrid()`

It does not calls Search() on server side and popup gets vanished.

What can be problem???

Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable postback on an asp Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683746/how-to-disable-postback-on-an-asp-button)

Comment: plz read my full question...its not the same or even near to it

Comment: i highly recommend you to use jquery instead, and in your title you said page is posting back after use of page method, but in the description, you are saying the page methods aren't called?

Comment: I have used in my program but it is not getting called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think You should Use `Static`

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static void Search()
    {
        availableMembers();
    }
```

Comment: dhanyawad devlekar bhau :)

Comment: Ho saheb.. Naredra Modi ... next PM