# How can I prevent postback while still allowing javascript to run?

Tags: c#, asp.net

One portion of this Asp.Net page contains this:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="get">
    Enter Employee Name or Click Search to Return All:
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="participant" ></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="get" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="Search" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Which is powered by this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#get").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                document.getElementById('<%= userTable.ClientID %>').style.display = "block";
                getUserNames();
            });
            $("#content_contentPlaceHolder_participant").keypress(function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                    $("#get").click();
                }
            });
        });
```

This works everywhere but Chrome. Using the enter key to submit this field in Chrome causes a full page reload.

I tried adding this in the code behind, but it prevents the javascript from firing:

```
participant.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "return (event.keyCode!=13);");
```

**How can I fix this, so that the enter key does not cause postback, but still fires the JS?**

Comment: try ``return false`` instead of ``preventDefault``

Comment: Add `OnClientClick="return false;"` on the ASP:Button control. So it looks like this: `<asp:Button runat="server" ID="get" OnClientClick="return false;" Text="Search" />`

Comment: This has many suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/683746/2589202

Comment: are you sure that this javascript is called ? this code `$("#get")` is probably must be `$("#<%=get.ClientID%>")`

Comment: @anwyatt While looking at you code... Why is it a serverside button anyway? Just make it a normal html button and you'll be fine.

Comment: @Schadensbegrenzer It actually was just a regular HTML button, I made it server side so I could wrap it in a panel after I noticed this happening. Before that the enter key was still triggering the global asp.net form.

Comment: @Aristos the Javascript DOES work, even in Chrome - clicking the button works as expected. My problem is the global ASp.Net form is triggered and causes postback.

Comment: @anwyatt Then I think that the `DefaultButton` on the panel is take action ! and when you press enter is make the post back.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by adding an additional `preventDefault()`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#get").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById('<%= userTable.ClientID %>').style.display = "block";
            getUserNames();
        });
        $("#content_contentPlaceHolder_participant").keypress(function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                event.preventDefault(); // <-- added this line
                $("#get").click();
            }
        });
});
```