# fullcalendar custombutton click removes html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar-4

I've a Fullcalendar site where I use the customButtons option to add two buttons. I also use the jquery .apppend function to add a dropdown and a textfield in the header. When I click the custom button the dropdown and textfield I added disappear. I can't find the reason. Can someone help me with this problem?

This is my code for the custom button. It sets the filter option and changes the icon on the button.

```
customButtons: {
filterButton: {
  text: '',
  click: function() {
    var newFilterResourcesWithEvents = ! calendar.getOption('filterResourcesWithEvents');
    calendar.setOption('filterResourcesWithEvents', newFilterResourcesWithEvents);
    tekst();
  }
 }
},
```

But it also removes these elements. The code for the append for the dropdown and textinput is.

```
$("#calendar .fc-resource-area .fc-widget-header .fc-cell-text").eq(0).append('<div class="form-inline"><div id="resourceddldiv"><select class="selectpicker" id="resourceddl" data-container="body"></select></div><input type="text" id="filter" placeholder="filter" size="15" style="margin-left:40px";></div>');
```

before click
[image: before click]
after click
[image: after click]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting a postback, and it is not refreshing your JS on the page. I can't tell where you have your elements placed in your JS files. The button defaults to submit, so you need to prevent that default if you are wanting to not do a postback.

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Put this with your buttons event to stop the postback, and it won't refresh your page causing you to lose those elements.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion within the custom button function, but still the same result.

The elements are appended right after the calendar render. I tried to append them again after a rerender, but that didn't help.

Comment: Here is an example of how you implement the ```preventDefault()```. If you are having your elements disappear due to you clicking the button, 9 times out of 10 it is going to be due to your postback, how your JS is arranged for the postback, etc.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959826/how-can-i-prevent-postback-while-still-allowing-javascript-to-run

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by appending the elements again after the function from the custom button. If I used the event.preventDefault(); the function wasn't executed at all. And because the whole table is rendered again after the function the only solution was appending it again.