# How to Execute a Javascript in ASP Button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, combobox, telerik, radeditor

I am using a JavaScript to add some content from a ComboBox to RadEditor using a button. It is working fine with HTML button. But, I need to Add another comobox and it should also do the same job, but it need to be hidden some times (Second Combobox is Not Visible All the time)..

```
<input type="button" onclick="pasteTextInEditor('<%=cmbOne.ClientID%>')" value="Add This Feild" class="button"/>
                                  <script type="text/javascript">
                                      function pasteTextInEditor(clientId) {

                                          var combo = $find(clientId);

                                          var editor = $find("<%=editorX.ClientID%>");
                                          editor.pasteHtml(combo.get_selectedItem().get_value());
                                      }
                                 </script>
```

Above Code is used to put contents from Combo to Rad Editor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure, you can execute this function on client side with 
OnClientClick event provided from asp button.

Example:

```
OnClientClick="function (button,args){alertText('Alerted Text','Alerted Title');}
```

Comment: It Works.. Thankx. Is there anyway to stop post back? - @Rafał Czabaj

Comment: If you want to stop Postback from asp:button just set property AutoPostBack="false" in the button properties in the aspx file.

Comment: It Didin't Work
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" CssClass="button" 
                                        Text="Button" AutoPostBack="false" />

Comment: Okay, at the end of your javascript function in the OnClientClick event add return false; that should prevent the postback according to: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683746/how-to-disable-postback-on-an-asp-button[/link]