# How to make a button not submit

Tags: asp.net, forms, button

I understand that button created are all of type submit. So I am using the `.CommandName` property of the button class to make it not a submit type as [suggested here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button(v=vs.110).aspx) The way I make my button is like this

```
ePanel.Controls.Add(New Button With {.CssClass = "button enlargeMapButton", 
.Text = "Enlarge Map", .CommandName = "Sort"})
```

Upon inspecting the element I get this in the DOM

[image]

and clicking the button actually tries to submit the form and reloads the form section. Am I missing something here?

**EDIT**

The full set of code. The relevant part.

```
Private Shared Function AddPropertyMap(ByVal currentTable As Table, ByRef 
propertyMapValue As Boolean) As Table
  ***Stuff createing other thing cells rows table etc***
  Dim MapControl As New Panel() With {.ID = "MapControl", .Visible = True, .CssClass = "MapBlock"}
  Dim ePanel As New Panel
  ePanel.Controls.Add(New Button With {.CssClass = "button enlargeMapButton", .Text = "Enlarge Map", .CommandName = "Sort"})
  MapControl.Controls.Add(ePanel)
  **creating Other control/things to other cell**
  Dim tCell3 As New TableCell()
  tCell3.Controls.Add(MapControl)
  Dim tRow As New TableRow()
  tRow.Cells.Add(tCell1)
  tRow.Cells.Add(tCell2)
  tRow.Cells.Add(tCell3)
  Dim newTable As New Table
  newTable.Rows.Add(tRow)
  Return newTable
```

Comment: Can you supply the full code from where the button is declared in the aspx file?  That will help determine what's wrong, I think...

Comment: It actually made in a .vb file from a visual basic project. This is old code that I am maintaining/using to "build" a form

Comment: This may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683746/how-to-disable-postback-on-an-asp-button - i.e. set the OnClientClick attribute/property to `"return false"`.

Comment: I suggest you use the asp.net tag.

Comment: Do you want your button to still perform postback, but not as a form submit button or do you want it to remain "client-only" button ?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I want it "client Only".

Comment: @JackThor then use @Mark's suggestion. add property `.OnClientClick = "return false"`

Comment: @Mark Thanks for the link what they suggested work. If you can make and answer with that link I will accept it. Otherwise I will delete this post.

Comment: Might be better to leave the post, as it could come in handy for someone in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop a `Button` from posting back by returning `false` from the `OnClientClick` handler.  In the simplest case, you can just set the `.OnClientClick` property to `"return false"`.

```vb
ePanel.Controls.Add(New Button With {.CssClass = "button enlargeMapButton", .Text = "Enlarge Map", .CommandName = "Sort", .OnClientClick = "return false"})
```

This could also call a client side JavaScript function that returns false to suppress the postback.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683746/how-to-disable-postback-on-an-asp-button) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a cleaner approach be to use...

```
UseSubmitBehavior="false"
```

You could also add...

```
CausesValidation="false"
```

to prevent the button adding some unnecessary markup to the page.