# asp.net: How to make a listen button

Tags: audio, dictionary, client, listen

As you can see from the dictionary webs (like [this web](http://www.thefreedictionary.com)), Google translate, ... They provide us a listen button to hear how the word would sound.

I'm trying to make a listen button for my web site, let me describe how I get here:
The default button always posts back when I click it, so I use the "return false" on OnClientClick to prevent post back as [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683746/how-to-disable-postback-on-an-asp-button) suggests. Then I have to use a javascript function to handle the button's click event, but the C# code behind is used to get the audio's link which is stored in the SQL server database, so I can't get the javascript function to play the audio I want.

So here's my situation:

what I have:

- the audio wav file
- the link of the audio file which is stored in SQL    server database

What I need: The listen button like dictionary websites have.

Thanks for reading.