# aspx button prevent postback onclick (c#)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

The code below shows some HTML with a `<asp:Button>` element.

```
<asp:Button ID="CalculateG481" runat="server" Text="Calculate" OnClick="CalculateG481_Click" />
```

This calls the function `CalculateG481_Click` but then posts back.

I have tried using `OnClientClick="return false"` but this simply prevents the button from executing `CalculateG481_Click`

I have also tried `OnClick="CalculateG481_Click; return false;"` as well to no avail.

EDIT: `CalculateG481_Click` is a C# Codebehind function.

Comment: Set `OnClientClick="CalculateG481_Click();"`. I'm assuming `CalculateG481_Click` is a javascript function. Make sure you return false from that function to prevent a postback. See [similar SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683746/how-to-disable-postback-on-an-asp-button)

Comment: @Michael Sorry no, CalculateG481_Click is a C# codebehind function, i have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @ChrisGeo You are using Server Button Control, and you do not want to post back. Do you want to call client-side JavaScript function before posting back to server? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Win I am creating a calculator, and when the user clicks the button i want to update their input values in the input boxes, without the post back closing the tab of the calculator on the page.

Comment: @ChrisGeo You can either use regular input html tag with client-side calculation or Server Button Control with Ajax based on your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are doing is really strange - **you cannot call Server-Side Button Event from Client-Side JavaScript**.

You can either use regular input html tag with pure Client-Side calculation or Server Button Control with **Ajax** based on your requirement.

Easiest way is to use Ajax [UpdatePanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx), and place everything inside it.

Comment: The update panel did the trick, enclosing the main tab with the panel worked. Thank you!