# asp disable button for the whole session

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, button

I would like to disable a submit button on a webform like proposed in:
[How to disable postback on an asp Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683746/how-to-disable-postback-on-an-asp-button)

But the button should stay disabled, even when the user navigates to some other webpage in the application (like admin page) and then navigates back to the original page; (in my case the button is then not disabled anymore). So is there a way that this button stays disabled (for instance until the user logs off from the application) even in such events and for the whole session until the user logs off?

Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Add a session variable, example Session("btnDisabled") in the event where you want this to happen and check against it every time a page with the button loads.

```
If session("btnDisabled")=true then btnSomething.enabled=false
```

then when the user is logged out, you change that variable, either kill it or set it to false.