# Prevent Server Postback on Button Click

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Can I avoid `postback` on button click (don't go in page_load method),

despite, Call the handler directly.

I tried `html` button, `asp button`, `link button`, but didn't get my goal.

Is it possible?

Comment: `Call event handler without postback, Is it possible?` Yes, it is all you need to do is wrap your button and other content inside **Update Panel**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable postback on an asp Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683746/how-to-disable-postback-on-an-asp-button)

Comment: @Prabhat I tried the same solution, but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `OnClientClick`. It will call the function (jquery function) you want to execute then use return false to avoid pageload. In your button add:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="yourfunction(); return false;" />
```

If you want to call code behind function without postback then there are two ways to do this:

1. Use UpdatePanel. [You can read this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers).
2. or Use page methods:

Add a static method to your page, decorated with the WebMethod attribute:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void MyMethod(string Param) 
{
}
```

Enable page methods in your ScriptManager:

```
<asp:ScriptManager EnablePageMethods="True" ... />
```

And then you can call it from the client side, using JavaScript (`OnClientClick` event of your button).

```
PageMethods.MyMethod("value", successCallback, errorCallback);
```

For more details read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398998.aspx

Hope it will help you..!

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript if you want to disable post back
try the below code

```
<asp:button runat="server".... OnClientClick="myfunction(); return false;" />
```

by doing this,it will cancel the postback

Comment: No, I wanna call server side handler, without postback on server. your solution does not carry the program flow to server side.